# Change CSS on a wordpress post

Tags: css

I want to change the Right-Hand style on the post http://sherridon.bluefrogclients.com/2010/12/15/wellington.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

this should get you started

.one_third.last{}

Answer (score 1):

You can easily target styles to a single post by using [`body_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) in your template:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

You do already have some similarly targetable classes on the page:

```
<div class="post-176 post type-post hentry category-house" id="post-176">
```

But those styles can intersect with styles on, say, [a date archive page](http://sherridon.bluefrogclients.com/2010/12):

```
<div class="post-176 post type-post hentry category-house" id="post-176">
```